# Why is the Ku Klux Clan an Christian terrorism organisation?

Tags: religion, terrorism, fascism

the [wikipdeia article of the Ku Klux Clan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ku_Klux_Klan) says

> Though members of the KKK swore to uphold American values and
>   Christian morality, virtually every Christian denomination officially
>   denounced the KKK.

and

> **Political ideology**:
>
> - Christian terrorism
> - Anti-Catholicism
> - Antisemitism

1. **=>** why can the behavior of the Ku Klux Clan be described as Christian terrorism?
2. **=>** How does the Ku Klux Clan refer to Christian ideals?
3. **=>** How does the Ku Klux Clan compare to terrorism groups like Taliban or IS?

Comment: VtC as trivial; the first quote answer the first question - their internal oaths were sworn on the ideology of Christianity.  The second question is probably a question for religion, not history, and isn't relevant; we don't judge terrorist organizations by our perception of their orthodoxy. The third question is explicitly opinion based.

Comment: What about #1 and #2 is unclear after you read the article you linked to?

Comment: Vtc as off-topic for history SE

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: No its not a school assignment. I ask just because of curiosity.

Comment: @nvoigt  @ Mark
wikipedia says partly the Ku Klux Clan refers sometimes to Christian ideology, but doesn't say why wikipedia estimates this so. => I want the background information which provide evidence for that statement. Sure, wikipedia refers to lots of books as sources, but i thought as "entry point" i could maybe ask here. Additionally, i thought a kind of fact based comparison would be surely possible and not certainly opinion based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ku Klux Klan is a Christian terrorist group because they engaged in acts of terror. They burned down churches and executed people they considered harmful to their vision of Christian and American ideology.

There still exist people who claim to be Christians and forbid interracial marriages. There still exist people who claim to be Christians and claim white supremacy. There still exist people who claim to be Christians and harbor significant anti-Semitic sentiments. When these people act on those beliefs to terrorize other people by threatening politicians who support racial equality, to burn down black churches, or to hang Jews from a tree, they become Christian terrorists.

While the Ku Klux Klan may have harbored anti-Semitic sentiments, they are best known for their anti-Negro sentiments. There was a common teaching in the 19th Century that white men were the descendants of Seth, Negroes were the descendants of Ham, and Asians were the descendants of Japheth. They saw the domination of the Negroes (Ham) and the incursions of the Asians (Japheth) as fulfillment of the prophecy of Noah that Canaan (a son of Ham) would serve Seth and that Japheth would live in the tents of his brothers. This educated their ideology of white supremacy.

This ideology of white supremacy turned into violence and terrorism after the Civil War. The Negroes were now equals to white men and the KKK felt that this was a violation of the Biblical prophecy, so they acted to suppress the freedmen and their allies. Per the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ku_Klux_Klan) that you referenced, you see that they threatened and assassinated Negro politicians. This is similar to the actions we hear about on the news performed by Al Qaeda, ISIL, the Taliban, and other terrorist groups in the Middle East.